# Filtering an Array based on another Boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, ramda.js

Say I have two arrays:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const predicateArray = [true, false, false, true]
```

I want the return value to be:

```
[1, 4]
```

So far, I have come up with:

```
pipe(
  zipWith((fst, scnd) => scnd ? fst : null)),
  reject(isNil) 
)(data, predicateArray)
```

Is there a cleaner / inbuilt method of doing this?

Solution in Ramda is preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works in native JS (ES2016):

```
const results = data.filter((d, ind) => predicateArray[ind])
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'd' parameter? It is not used, so...

Comment: @CarlosToscano-Ochoa Positional parameters cannot be skipped. It doesn’t matter what it’s called, you have to specify it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a Ramda solution for some reason, a variant of the answer from richsilv is simple enough:

```
R.addIndex(R.filter)((item, idx) => predicateArray[idx], data)
```

Ramda does not include an `index` parameter to its list function callbacks, for some good reasons, but [`addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) inserts them.

Comment: Nice solution! Can you share a bit more about the reasons why the index is not included?

Comment: I'm afraid it's too involved to discuss here, but you can see the relevant Ramda issues: [452](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/452) (contentious), [484](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/484), [729](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/729), and [1061](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1061)

Answer (score 0):

As asked, with `ramda.js` :

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const predicateArray = [true, false, false, true];

R.addIndex(R.filter)(function(el, index) {
  return predicateArray[index];
}, data); //=> [2, 4]
```

**Updated** example to fix issue referenced in the comment.

Comment: This wont work if the data array contains duplicate value, as indexOf will return only the first index